# passing array to controller function in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have array of id's. I am getting id's in string in $user_id.

```
$array=explode(',', $user_id);

  echo http_build_query($array);
```

It outputs 0=3&1=4 but when I Pass $array as a parameter to controller function via url like this..

```
<?php echo base_url()."index.php/requesthandler/cancelRequest/$payment_id/$booking_id/$array";?>
```

And when I print_r($array) in controller it gives me output only string that is 'Array'.So how do I Pass that array to controller function via url??
$booking_id and $payment_id are other parameters for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convet array to query string, please use `http_build_query` functio with url, try this

```
    <?php echo base_url()."index.php/requesthandler/cancelRequest
       /$payment_id/$booking_id?".http_build_query($array);?>
```

OR

You can also pass same string with single key

```
<?php echo base_url()."index.php/requesthandler/cancelRequest
       /$payment_id/$booking_id?user_ids={$user_id}"; ?>
```

And parse on user like this

```
<?php  print_r(explode(',', $this->input->get("user_ids"));?>
```

Comment: when i use your first ans it gives me error uri contains disallowed characters when i click on link

Comment: @KedarB , OK please allow `0-9` char in query string... you can set allow char in `/aplication/config.php` file `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`, i would recommend 2nd option.

Comment: what is user_ids after $booking_id

Comment: @KedarB this is query string `key` that will be used to parse `GET` value see below in ans.